# Can Jenkins send mail notify with attachment?

Tags: email, plugins, attachment, jenkins

can Jenkins send mail notify to recipients with attachments? What is more important for me (optional), it could also read from file *.xls and add this to email text.

Or can i add from my system variable to data, which is sending by plugin of jenkins (ext mail) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

New answer, as of September 2011: **Yes**. [Issue 9018](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9018) has been resolved.

Starting with version 2.15 of the Jenkins email-ext plugin, you can send attachments in Jenkins build notifications. See the Jenkins wiki here:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: the jenkins wiki always loads so slow.

Answer (score 1):

how I make a Jenkins send me an Email **always** with attached HTML file when the Jenkins trigger

**1)** press "Configuration"

[image]

**2)** in the top part of configuration press "Post-build Actions"

[image]

**3)** press on "add post build action "
and choose "editable email notification"

[image]

**4)** after it been added
enter "Project Recipient List" a emails you want to send (possible to add more than one mail , like in the example)

[image]

**5)** scroll down, add to the "Attachments"  direction to the file you want to send

[image]

**6)** in the end of the page press on button "advanced settings"  from the right side

[image: ![enter image description here]

7. **add trigger to the sending email by the option you prefer **

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was recently posted on the Jenkins JIRA: [Issue 9018](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9018).  That site is not responding for me right now, so I can't even see what the status is.

Regarding the e-mails in the XLS file, I did a search of the Jenkins plug-ins and could not find anything for "XLS" or "Excel".  If you're Jenkins instance is running on Windows, you could use VBScript and COM to either export the list to a parsable format like TAB or CVS; or you could try to programmatically look through the list for the e-mails and get the VBScript to return them as one big string.  This forum has a pretty clear example of opening a workbook, selecting the appropriate worksheet, and then iterating through the cells: [XLS & VBScript](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/VBScript-amp-Excel-m32435.aspx).  Oh, and I just remembered that if you have newer versions of Visual Studio and Office, there's interoperability there that might be easier; though I've never tried that combo.

I hope this helps,
Zachary

Comment: right, i used extended notify mail plugin to send mail in html format. Before that i used autohotkey and powershell to save sheet into html format. Then i joined sheet in html and my text. That big string i used to send something by email.