# Jenkins email notification for build failure due to compile error

Tags: email, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, email-ext

I have continuous integration setup using jenkins and also integrated selenium scripts for nightly build. I also have editable email notification for sending emails in case of any build failure.

The default content for editable email notification is

> $DEFAULT_CONTENT
>
> ${JELLY_SCRIPT,template="text"}
>
> ${FAILED_TESTS}

This content give me clear picture if there is any fail in the selenium script with full stacktrace.

The problem is that, if the jenkins build got failed due to compile error or any other failure reasons, the email notification is not providing any reason about the failure. It simply says **No tests ran.**

How to make jenkins to send mail notification with the failure reason, if the build got failed due to compile time error ?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach build logs and any reports that your selenium has producing with the editable email notification.
Below is a screenshot of what you can do:
[image]

Attached Logs can give you Info on `build` `failure` and other details And reports can be `customized` as you need.

More links:

- [Can Jenkins send mail notify with attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952503/)
- [Display HTML page inside mail body with Email-ext plugin in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066936/)
- [How to include git changelog in Jenkins emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773010/)

Comment: hi chandan. thanks for the response. i would like to include the failure reason in the mail content itself instead of attaching the complete build log

Comment: Not sure, how you want to pinpoint on the failure of the selenium suite, a report is much more reliable to do that, you can add git commit logs on this particular build in the email and you can trigger different mail on build failure to narrow down the failure reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two jobs , one is for triggering build for every check and one for running automation suite.

It may resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer