# Need to include ATU reports excel content in emai

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I want to add the excel  content inside jenkins email body.  The excel content includes the information about the total test case passed and total cases failed.. i wanto send these columns in my mail body.Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Jenkins send mail notify with attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952503/can-jenkins-send-mail-notify-with-attachment)

Comment: No i dont want to add as an attachment.. i want to send the content of an excel in email body